# How to make a global destructuring form this in class?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a global destructuring from this in class for example

```
class Car {
    constructor(
        color,
        speed,
        type,
    ) {
        this.color = color;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.type = type;
    }

    method1() {
      const { color, speed, type } = this;
      // do something with speed, color, type;
    }

    method2() {
        const { color, speed, type } = this;
        // do another thing with speed, color, type;
    }

    method3() {
        const { color, speed, type } = this;
        // do another thing with speed, color, type;
    }
}
```

instead of destructuring this in each method is there a way to do this as global for all methods

and in each method instead of call this i just reference the variable

Comment: Why do you feel the need to destructure this? You can use `this.color` wherever you need that variable inside a method.

Comment: why not `this.color` ?

Comment: if i used `this` in each variable i reference it feels like redundant and repetitive. that's why i was going for this approach. also if i have like 20 variables and i use them in each function or method imagine the repetitive code i write each time i use these variables inside each method

Comment: I mean the global destructure *is* `this`... how do you imagine accessing those variables with a "global destructure"? like just write `color`, `speed` etc. inside the methods? 'Cause that's not how scopes work.

Comment: yeah i understand, that's why i asked is there an approach to do something like this @Onheiron

Comment: Using `this` is exactly how class member access is designed to work. So no, other than moving the variables to the global scope (i.e. outside the `Car` class, where you'd lose the information about *which* instance of Car has that color/type/speed) the only way to use those variables without using `this` is to destructure them as you suggest in your question.

Comment: @sasharomanov You *should* use `this.` to make clear that you're referencing an instance property, not a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. If you want to create local variables in each method, you cannot do that globally.

The only alternative would be to not use a `class` but a factory function which builds closures over the constructor arguments:

```
function Car(color, speed, type) {
    return {
        get color() { return color; },
        get speed() { return speed; },
        get type() { return type; },
        method1() {
          // do something with speed, color, type;
        },
        method2() {
            // do another thing with speed, color, type;
        },
        method3() {
            // do another thing with speed, color, type;
        }
    };
}
```